# Delete the oldest date entitled subfolder

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, delete-file

I have this script which is created to backup a cube within an application. It runs every saturday and it created a sub folder within the application folder. Due to space requirements I've had to delete the oldest folder every week. I need to create a script to do that.

Here's the backup code:

```
:: Create folder for App Db if it does not exist
IF NOT EXIST %BACKUPDIR%%1"\"%2 GOTO MAKEDIR
GOTO CONT
:MAKEDIR
mkdir %BACKUPDIR%%1"\"%2

GOTO :CONT



:CONT
cd %BACKUPDIR%%1"\"%2

:: Get todays date
for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do (
set my_day=%%j
set my_month=%%i
set my_year=%%k )
set datestamp=%my_month%%my_day%%my_year%
::echo %datestamp%


:: Create date folder for app db
IF NOT EXIST %BACKUPDIR%%1"\"%2"\"%datestamp% GOTO MAKEDIRTIMEDATE

:MAKEDIRTIMEDATE
G:
cd %BACKUPDIR%%1"\"%2"\
mkdir %BACKUPDIR%%1"\"%2"\%datestamp%

:: Copy otl, csc, rul, rep files from App to Backup fodler
XCOPY %APPFOLDER%"\app\"%1"\"%2"\*.csc" %BACKUPDIR%%1"\"%2"\"%datestamp% /Y
XCOPY %APPFOLDER%"\app\"%1"\"%2"\*.rul" %BACKUPDIR%%1"\"%2"\"%datestamp% /Y
XCOPY %APPFOLDER%"\app\"%1"\"%2"\*.otl" %BACKUPDIR%%1"\"%2"\"%datestamp% /Y
XCOPY %APPFOLDER%"\app\"%1"\"%2"\*.rep" %BACKUPDIR%%1"\"%2"\"%datestamp% /Y
XCOPY %APPFOLDER%"\app\"%1"\"%2"\*.ind" %BACKUPDIR%%1"\"%2"\"%datestamp% /Y



cd %SCRIPTDIR%

:: Move data file from script dir to backupdir if data file exist If not exit out of code
IF NOT EXIST %SCRIPTDIR%%1"_"%2"_AllData.txt" GOTO EXIT

:END

 MOVE %SCRIPTDIR%%1"_"%2"_AllData*.txt" %BACKUPDIR%%1"\"%2"\"%datestamp%


 GOTO EXIT


:EXIT

exit /b
```

As you can see ever week a new folder is created with the creation data as its title (i.e. 102913). That folder is a subfolder of an application. I need a script to deleted the oldest folder.

So far I've tried (using test folders):

```
FORFILES -p "C:\Oracle\test\New folder\new folder" -s -m *.rul /D -<7> /C "cmd IF @isdir == TRUE" /c del @path
```

and

```
forfiles -p "C:\Oracle\test\New folder\new folder" -s -m *.rul /D -<7> /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

Any suggestion would be useful.

Comment: The script above has mismatched quotes.  If it runs then it is a miracle. ;)

Comment: Which one... the backup code or my delete scripts because the backup runs. please help i'm really not good at this.

Answer (score 1):

```
set "backupDir=C:\Oracle\test\New folder\new folder"
for /F "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /ad /tc /o-d /b "%backupDir%"') do set "oldest=%backupDir%\%%f"
echo "%oldest%"
```

Get directory list ordered by creation date descending, only incuding directories, in brief format. Last line in list will be stored in variable %oldest% with the working directory prefixed.

Comment: Just wanted to simplify the code. Decided not to take speed in consideration because: (1) if space is such a requirement (and olap data is usually really big) there will be not be a lot of folders (2) It is a previous steep to a backup, which is not really a fast process. With this two ideas in mind i tried to write the minimum amount of code but keep it legible.

Comment: this script doesn't delete the folders.

Comment: @Rai: No, it doesn't. It just echo the name of the directory to delete (to avoid undesired deletes on code test). Change `echo "%oldest%"` to `rmdir /s /q "%oldest%"`

Comment: tired that as well. will this delete the folders or the files?

Also should i try incorporating what you posted with the forfiles script?

Comment: @Rai: The `for` command searchs the oldest directory. `rmdir /s /q ...` is a command to recursive delete the directory, subdirectories and files below it.